# Javascript/jquery: select element which is visible and has name, get height and apply This to another div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use jquery to select elements called `fieldset` which are `visible`, (there should only be 1), and then get it's height (as fieldsetHeight). I then want to set the height of a div with the id of `variable-div` to == fieldsetHeight.

This is what I have so far:

```
var fieldsetHeight = ((document.(fieldset).is(':visible').offsetHeight) + 'px');
document.getElementById('variable-div').style.height = fieldsetHeight;
```

But it's not working...

Comment: What does it have to do with json?

Comment: Well `document.(fieldset)` is a syntax error. If when you say the elements are "called fieldset" you mean that that is the `name` property you could try `$('select[name="fieldset"]:visible')` to get the element with jQuery. `$('select[name="fieldset"]:visible')[0].offsetHeight` to get the height of the first matching element.

Comment: What does variable `fieldset` contain?

Comment: @nnnnnn fieldset is a html tag which is part of a form. like this:

 `<fieldset>
        <p class="fs-question">What sort of trip would you like to go on?</p>
        <textarea name="description" placeholder="e.g. Somewhere in Bali with a surf beach, a hot-tub and a mini-bar." rows="3"></textarea>
    </fieldset>`

I have 3 fieldsets but only 1 is visible at a time. So i'm trying to get the height of the visible one and give that to a div. It sounds like you're a bit closer than me though, nnnnnn!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it this way :

```
var fieldsetHeight = $(document.getElementsByTagName("fieldset")).filter(':visible').height() + 'px';
document.getElementById('variable-div').style.height = fieldsetHeight;
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/f3PEX/

But hey, since you're using jQuery, why not :

```
var fieldsetHeight = $("fieldset").filter(':visible').height() + 'px';
$('#variable-div').height(fieldsetHeight);
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/f3PEX/1/

PS : If you need a JS only answer, remove the jQuery tag will you :)

Comment: Great! thanks so much hungerpain! works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Here is using only jQuery:

```
var fieldsetHeight = $($("fieldset:visible")[0]).height() + 'px';

if (confirm("Change height of div?")) {
    $('#variable-div').height( fieldsetHeight);
}
```

[working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f3PEX/2/)